# MVVM WPF Application Developer skill set

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What kind of skills should a WPF developer know to create MVVM applications?

Things like Attached Dependency Properties and DelegateCommands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good intro video/screencast on WPF and MVVM on Ch9; http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Continuum/MVVM/

Answer (score 1):

DataTemplate for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Binding. Followed closely by general WPF concepts.

Knowing a bit about similar patterns like MVP and MVC would also help.